# setProgress method doesn't update the ProgressBar when my file is being downloaded

Tags: android, android-progressbar

1. code to download the file:

   ```
   Dialog dialog;
   int totalSize = 0;
   ProgressBar mProgressBar;
   int downloadedSize = 0;

   public void downloadFile(){
       try {
           URL url = new URL("http://.../my_file.mp3");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
           urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

           urlConnection.connect();

           File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

           File dir = new File(SDCardRoot.getAbsolutePath(), "/dossier1/dossier2";
           dir.mkdirs();

           File file = new File(dir, "my_file.mp3");

           FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

           InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

           totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   mProgressBar.setMax(totalSize);
               }
           });

           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           int bufferLength = 0;

           while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
               fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
               downloadedSize += bufferLength;

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       mProgressBar.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                   }
               });
           }

           fileOutput.close();

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   //mProgressBar.dismiss();
               }
           });

       } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
           showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (final IOException e) {
           showError("Error : IOException " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       catch (final Exception e) {
           showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. showProgress method:

   ```
   public  void showProgress(){
   dialog = new Dialog(context);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
   dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");

   TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
   text.setText("Downloading...");
   cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
   cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
   dialog.show();

   mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
   mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
   mProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_progress));
   }
   ```
3. Layout for the mProgressDialog (myprogressdialog.xml in res/layout):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/layout_root"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dp">

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#FFF"
   android:text="hello"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   />

   <ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:progress="0"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
   android:maxHeight="10dip"
   android:minHeight="10dip"
   />

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/cur_pg_tv"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#0F0"
   android:text="hello"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:textStyle="bold|italic"    />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Xml for giving a blue color to the mProgressBar (blue_progress.xml in res/drawable)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:id="@android:id/background">
   <shape>
       <corners android:radius="5dip" />
       <gradient android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
           android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
           android:centerY="0.75"
           android:endColor="#ff747674"
           android:angle="270"
           />
   </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
   <clip>
       <shape>
           <corners android:radius="5dip" />
           <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
               android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
               android:centerY="0.75"
               android:endColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
               android:angle="270"
               />
       </shape>
   </clip>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
   ```

setProgress method doesn't update the ProgressBar when my file is being downloaded!
Can you suggest me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I'd suggest reading up on AsyncTask, as there are some really good tools in there that can help you update the UI thread asynchronously.
Async task allows you to run a task on the background thread, and when it is finished (or in progress), give updates to the UI.  Usually this allows you to skip making UI Runnables--but it depends on your situation.

Anyway,
The method you want to override is onProgressUpdate in an AsyncTask.  Also, it might save you some headaches trying to accomplish this in the future.

Good luck!  Hope that helps.